# Add grouping column to ordered table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
|id|sog|zoneId|
| 1| 20|     2|
| 2|  2|     2|
| 3| 10|     2|
| 4| 10|     1|
| 5|  3|     1|
| 6| 8 |     2|
| 7| 1 |     2|
| 8| 3 |     2|
| 9| 4 |     2|
```

Rows are sorted by the `id` column.

I want to make a query to return:

```
|id|sog|zoneId|grpId|
| 1| 20|     2|    1|
| 2|  2|     2|    1|
| 3| 10|     2|    1|
| 4| 10|     1|    2|
| 5|  3|     1|    2|
| 6| 8 |     2|    3|
| 7| 1 |     2|    3|
| 8| 3 |     2|    3|
| 9| 4 |     2|    3|
```

Comment: what exactly is the logic behind assigning the `grpId` value?

Comment: yeah, we should know when and why `grpId` is 1, 2 or 3

Comment: `grpId` must be ordered asc, value is not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [Itzik Ben-Gan's solution to islands and gaps](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf):

```
;with q as (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by id)
         - row_number() over (order by zoneid, id) as grp
      from thetable
)
select id, sog, zoneid,
       min (id) over(partition by zoneid, grp) as grp
  from q
 order by id
```

`Grp` remains the same as two sequences, `id` and `ZoneID, id` run along, but the numbers are neither ordered nor sequential. Ordered group number is constructed simply by taking min(id) per group. If you need sequential group number add another cte which retrieves `dense_rank() over(order by grp)`.

[Sql Fiddle this way](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71b41/4). (Thanks to w0lf).

Comment: +1, you've made me thinking, so I've added another solution for this

Answer (score 1):

If your Id is sequential and doesn't have gaps, then I think fastest way would be:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        T.id, T.sog, T.zoneId,
        1 as grpId
    from Table1 as T
    where T.id = 1

    union all

    select
        T.id, T.sog, T.zoneId,
        c.grpId + case when T.zoneId = c.zoneId then 0 else 1 end as grpId
    from cte as c
        inner join Table1 as T on T.id = c.id + 1
)
select c.id, c.sog, c.zoneId, c.grpId
from cte as c
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eac4/11)

If Id is not sequential or does have gaps, you can do:

```
;with cte1 as (
    select
        T.id, T.sog, T.zoneId,
        row_number() over (order by T.id) as row_num
    from Table1 as T
), cte2 as (
    select
        T.id, T.sog, T.zoneId, T.row_num,
        1 as grpId
    from cte1 as T
    where T.row_num = 1

    union all

    select
        T.id, T.sog, T.zoneId, T.row_num,
        c.grpId + case when T.zoneId = c.zoneId then 0 else 1 end as grpId
    from cte2 as c
        inner join cte1 as T on T.row_num = c.row_num + 1
)
select c.id, c.sog, c.zoneId, c.grpId
from cte2 as c
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eac4/15)

but I'm not sure if performance would be good for that

Comment: A warning: `cte.grp` is not ordered by ids (see zoneid = 2), so you cannot do `dense_rank` immediately. This is the reason why I have proposed dense_rank over min(id). See [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eac4/22).